# Have a file name with a part fixed (python)

Tags: python, title

I was wondering if it was possible to give to a file name a fixed part and a desired part chosen by the user?

For exemple my script is :

```
python3 script.py -name1 -name2
```

and I want to creat 2 files:

```
file1=open(name1+".aa","w")
file2=open(name2".ffa","w")
```

And the two files created would be if the user had used that:

```
python3 script.py -Bobo1 -JoJo2

BoBo1.aa
JoJo2.faa
```

As you can see, the user can choose the first part but the part ".aa" and ".faa" stay fixed.

Thank you :)

Comment: Is this your target? `file2=open("foobar"+name2+".ffa","w")`

Comment: The easiest solution would be `import sys; file1 = sys.argv[1][1:]; file2 = sys.argv[2][1:]`.

Comment: OK it works thank you :)